# Combo box items are hidden behind other controls.

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, rsyntaxtextarea

error screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3keuR.png]

The `JComboBox` items are obscured by `RSyntaxTextArea` in programs created with Java Swing.

This symptom does not occur when running the same program on a mac.
It only occurs in the windows environment.

Could someone give me some hint about the solution?

Comment: Typically you need to provide enough code for other people to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
comboBox.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

See [Mixing Lightweight and Heavyweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) for why this should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day.